# Angular2 jspm gulp typescript unexpected token @

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, jspm

I've just started learning about angular 2 and all the technologies that come with it and I'm trying to use gulp-jspm-build to create minified and "compiled" versions of my .ts files.
The problem is I get this error and I don't know how to solve it. Could i get some assistance pls

```
SyntaxError: app/menu/component.ts: Unexpected token (8:0)
   6 | import {OnInit} from "@angular/core/metadata/lifecycle_hooks";
   7 | 
>  8 | @Component({
     | ^
   9 |     selector: '[menu]',
  10 |     templateUrl: 'app/menu/template.html',
  11 | })
  at Parser.pp.raise...
```

I dont have a typings.json file, does that have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell to your transpiler that you work with decorators, as they are not supported natively yet (in tsconfig.json or in grunt / gulp configuration):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "experimentalDecorators": true, <- here
```

And then you have to import the component class from angular:

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

For your question about typings.json, it is not related. This file is used by typings (`npm install -g typings`) to manage typescript types. It helps your transpiler and your IDE to understand your usage of external libraries written in ES6 or ES5 (without typescript types).
See [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md) for more info.